# Mostrar div con varias consultas php al hacer click

Tags: php, javascript, css

Hola tengo una aplicación que muestra una consulta con varias lineas de daros (imagen, y nombres), tengo ademas un **div id="popup"** por cada linea donde imprimo estos mismos datos la cual la tengo oculta con **display: none**

al hacer click sobre la imagen de la primer linea de la consulta quiero que me muestre este **div id="popup"**  con la información de la primera linea.

Esto si me funciona cuando doy click en la foto de la primera linea, pero al darle click en la foto de la segunda linea, me aparece nuevamente la div relacionada con la primer linea de datos;

Las características a tomar en cuenta son que la **div id="popup"**  esta dentro de mi wile de la consulta para que automaticamente se repita con cada linea de la consulta a mi base de datos  (lo que si sucede ya que al hacer la prueba cambiando manualmente a display: flex si se muestran una div por cada linea de consulta conteniendo en ella los datos correspondientes a cada linea como los deseo).

Asumo que al dar clic en la primera imagen JavaScript encuentra la primer div con el nombre popup y la muestra en pantalla, y al darle clic en la segunda imagen me seguirá mostrando siempre la misma div y no la div popup correspondiente a la linea de datos a la que le di Click.

(estoy aprendiendo JavaScript, así que no se si hay una mejor manera de hacerlo).

Adjunto código desde la consulta PHP para que se comprenda de mejor manera.

````
$consultau=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM ALUMNS WHERE GRADE = '$grado'");
$contau=mysqli_num_rows($consultau);

            if ($contau>0){


    $consultaa=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM ALUMNS WHERE SECTION='$seccion' and GRADE='$grado' ORDER BY LASTNAME");

            while($rowu=mysqli_fetch_array($consultaa)){

$id=($rowu['ID']);
$name=($rowu['NAME']);
$lastname=($rowu['LASTNAME']);
$grade=($rowu['GRADE']);
$section=($rowu['SECTION']);

$fecha=($rowu['FECHA']);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Guatemala');
$fecha=date('Y/m/d');



$direccion=$nivel."/".$grade."/".$section."/".$id.".jpg";





            ?>
<!-- Datos de Consulta (varias lineas) -->             
<div id="info">

<a href="javascript:openit()"><img src="recursos/fotos/<?php echo $direccion; ?>" id="retrato"></a>

<div id="alumno">
<p id="nalumno"> <?php echo $name; ?></p>
    <p id="nalumno"><?php echo $lastname; ?></p>

</div>

 </div>


<!-- Datos de consulta escondidos para mostrar al dar click -->             

 <div id="popup"> 



<div id="" align="right"> 

    <div id="equis" style="display:block;
    position:fixed; margin:5;"><a href="javascript:closeit()"><img src="imagenes/cerrar.png" width="15px" id="x"></a></div>


<img id="" src="recursos/fotos/<?php echo $nivel."/".$grade."/".$section."/".$id.".jpg"; ?>" border="0" src="<>" height="80%" style="margin: auto; border-radius: 1%;"  alt="" /> 

<p id="nalumno"> <?php echo $name; ?></p><p id="nalumno"><?php echo $lastname; ?></p>

</div>         






</div> 

<?php    }}

else {
    echo ("algo salio mal");
            }?>


<!-- CSS -->            
<style type="text/css">
    #popup {
        background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.5);
        height: 100%; 
        width:100%; 
        justify-content: center; 
        align-items: center; 
        display: none; 
        position:fixed; 
        animation: agrandar 0.5s; 
        background-image: url('images/img_13.png'); top: 0;}



@keyframes agrandar{
    0%{
        transform:scale(0.5);
    }

    60%{
        transform:scale(1.05);
    }
    100%{
        transform:scale(1);
    }
     }
    </style>


 <!-- JavaScript-->         
<script type="text/javascript"> 


function openit(){ 
document.getElementById("popup" ).style.display = "flex"; style.align = 'right'; 
}  

function closeit(){ 
document.getElementById("popup" ).style.display = "none"; style.align = 'right';
} 

        </script>```
````

Comment: No entendí del todo tu problema, pero lo cierto es que para buscar los datos de la segunda consulta **la página tendrá que ir de nuevo al servidor y por lo tanto recargarse**. La mejor forma de resolver esto es con Ajax, que te permite ir y venir del servidor las veces que quieras, llevando y trayendo los datos que quieras y mostrándolos donde quieras **sin tener que recargar la página**. Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas con respuestas que explican cómo funciona Ajax. Te aconsejaría que te lances sin miedo por esa vía, porque no te arrepentirás.

Comment: Gracias amigo, edite la pregunta para mayor comprensión, ya que mi problema no esta en la consulta porque ya la tengo desde el inicio, el problema está en que quiero mostrar un div diferente por cada linea de código y no se como hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Ohhh OK, entonces puedes crear los divs dentro del `while` que lee los datos y luego los muestras al salir del `while`.

Comment: Pero no quiero mostrar todos los div solo el div correspondiente a la linea de datos a la que le doy click

Comment: Tu código PHP realmente no tiene relevancia, porque no se ve que estés armando un HTML y, de hecho, para saber lo que está pasando hay que ir de atrás hacia delante, viendo cómo queda el HTML y qué hace Javascript; resuelto eso ya se analizaría el PHP.